# Angular 2 Binding: Appending to src

Tags: angular

Sorry if this is simple, but just can't figure this out...

this code is  name.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Stores} from '../../stores.module';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {BranchService} from '../branch.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  positionMap: Stores;
  id: number;
  url: string;

  constructor(private storeService: BranchService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
       this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) =>  {
          this.id = +params['id'];
          this.positionMap = this.storeService.getStores(this.id);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

this code is  name.component.html

```html
    <iframe width="6000" height="500" id="gmap_canvas"
            src =  "https://maps.google.com/maps?q={{positionMap.street}}%20{{positionMap.num}}%20%{{positionMap.city}}&t=&z=20&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed"
            frameborder="0"
            scrolling="no"
            marginheight="30"
            marginwidth="5"
    >

    </iframe>
```

i need in

```html
src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q={{positionMap.street}}%20{{positionMap.num}}%20%{{positionMap.city}}&t=&z=20&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed"
```

where i'm binding positionMap in the url 
to see the data that i put

i want to see for example 
"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Brookline%20123%20%NewYork&t=&z=20&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed"

Answer (score 0):

```
getUrl(positionMap) {
    return "https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+
        positionMap.street+"%20"+positionMap.num+"%20%" +
        positionMap.city+"&t=&z=20&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed"
}
```

You could then change your html to this:

```
<iframe width="6000" height="500" id="gmap_canvas"
            [src] = "getUrl(positionMap)"
            frameborder="0"
            scrolling="no"
            marginheight="30"
            marginwidth="5">
</iframe>
```

Similarly if you do not want to use this approach , you should interpolate the src as you are doing currently, but change `src` to `[attr.scr]`

Another thing to remember is that while you are using src, try and use strin interpolation such as this example:

```
<img src={{positionMap?.url}} />
```

this will prevent changed after ngViewChecked error and will ensure that you always send a string.